# Compactly generated subgroups of locally compact Hausdorff groups

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I am reading a book where it is mentioned that any locally compact Hausdorff group is union of subgroups which are compactly generated. For this they take an open symmetric neighbourhood  $V$ of identity and consider $G_V:=\cup_{n=1}^\infty V^n$ Clearly, $G_V$ is an open subgroup. How can we show that $G=\cup_{V}G_V$ ?

Comment: If $G$ is connected, $G_V$ will be dense, so maybe look at components?

Comment: You should say that a compactly generated group is a topological group which is algebraically generated by a compact subset. The term "compactly generated" has a different meaning in topolopgy: A compactly generated space (or k-space) is a topological space whose topology is coherent with the family of all compact subspaces.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by a compactly generated group is meant a group generated by a compact neighborhood of the identity. Any locally compact group $G$ has such a neighborhood $U$ and so each element $x$ of $G$ is contained in a subgroup of $G$ generated by a compact neightborhood $U\cup\{x\}$ of the identity.